# Convert results from query to json object

Tags: json, reactjs

I am attempting to convert an api from PHP to react.js. my data looks like this:

| s | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 4/1 |
| B | 4 | 4/1 |
| A | 2 | 4/2 |
| B | 5 | 4/2 |
| A | 3 | 4/3 |
| B | 6 | 4/3 |

I pass json back to the app and it's built like this in PHP.

```
     $graph_arr['bar']['series'][$s] += (int) $c;
     $graph_arr['line']['series'][$s][] = (int) $c;
```

the resulting json looks like this

```
{line: 
   {labels: ['4/1','4/2','4/3'],  //already have this figured out 
    series: [{ name: 'A', data: [1,2,3]},
             { name: 'B', data: [4,5,6]}
  ]}
}
```

How would I do this in react, new to react.js so I am not too familiar everything works or is constructed yet.

```
  const graph_data = [['a',1,'4/1'],['a',2,'4/1'],['a',3,'4/1'], 
       ['a',4,'4/4'],['b',5,'4/1'],['b',6,'4/1'],['b',7,'4/1'],['b',8,'4/4']]

     const series = Object.entries(graph_data).map((row,i) => { })
```

edit:
found this [How to group an array of objects by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key). which is close

Answer (score -1):

You can treat it just like you do an array in PHP.

```
jsonData["line"]["series"][0].name
```

You can also extract (deconstruct) the data out

```
const jsonData = {
  line: {
    labels: ["4/1", "4/2", "4/3"], //already have this figured out
    series: [
      { name: "A", data: [1, 2, 3] },
      { name: "B", data: [4, 5, 6] }
    ]
  }
};

  const { line } = jsonData;
  const { labels, series } = line;

 {labels}   
 {labels[0]}
 {series.map((data) => data.name)}
```

I put them in an example with a couple of different ways for you:
https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-keller-3ott6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks!  The jsonData is what I'm looking to create from   const data = {['a',1,'4/1'],['a',2,'4/1'],['a',3,'4/1'],['a',4,'4/4'],['b',5,'4/1'],['b',6,'4/1'],['b',7,'4/1'],['b',8,'4/4']}. sorry for the confusion